# Bitwise XOR in sqlite - bitwise NOT not working as I expect

Tags: android, sqlite, bitwise-operators

I try to update flag in sqlite database.

I need to remove bit from my flag. Current flag vallue is 11.

In Java I simple do:

```
newflag = flag  ^ 2;
//newflag = 9
```

In SQL I try:

```
... SET flag = flag | ~2 ...
```

Now flag in db = -1. Why?

I try this in SQLite maganer for Firefox.

```
SELECT 9 | 2
```

returns 11, but

```
SELECT 11 | ~2
```

returns -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question (why does 11 | ~2 evaluate to -1), let's break it up. First the bitwise complement:

```
> SELECT ~2;
-3
```

Using binary notation, this is what's happening:

```
 2 : 00000000000000000000000000000010
~2 : 11111111111111111111111111111101
-3 : 11111111111111111111111111111101
```

SQLite takes your 2, applies a bitwise complement, and interprets it as a signed integer. In SQLite, ~n (where n is an integer value) is mathematically equivalent to -(n)-1, because it flips the sign bit along with all the other bits. To understand this better, read up on Two's complement:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Next the bitwise or:

```
> SELECT 11 | ~2;
-1
```

Again in binary:

```
     11 : 00000000000000000000000000001011
     ~2 : 11111111111111111111111111111101
11 | ~2 : 11111111111111111111111111111111
     -1 : 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

As for emulating your Java: your Java uses the bitwise XOR operator (^). To emulate a bitwise XOR in sqlite, you can use this general form:

```
(~(a&b))&(a|b)
```

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg02250.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to tag onto bsa's very thorough answer, to turn off a bit in an integer, and using the OP's example, you can simply:

```
SELECT 11 & ~2;  -- result is 9
```

So "~2" has every bit on except the "2" bit and performs a bitwise AND with the flags, forcing the 2 bit off.

BTW, if you're certain a particular bit is ON, you can turn it off simply by subtraction.

E.g.   SELECT 11 - 2;  -- result is 9

Conversely, if certain a bit is OFF, you can turn it ON by addition.